# Python , Raspberry pi, Firestore project ID

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to connect to my firestore database from my Raspberry pi 3 usig the code given in the firestore documentation but the sample code says that the Project ID of the database has to be set in the environment variable, which I am not able to do.. 
Code:

```
from google.cloud import firestore
import google.cloud.exceptions


def quickstart_new_instance():
    # [START quickstart_new_instance]
    from google.cloud import firestore

    # Project ID is determined by the GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variable
    db = firestore.Client()
    # [END quickstart_new_instance]

    return db
```

Link to snippet: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/firestore/cloud-client/snippets.py

Comment: Why can't you set the environment variable?

Comment: I don't know how to go about it...can you show me how to add a firestore database ID as a Raspberry pi environment variable??

Comment: I've never done that myself, but there seem some great options in here: https://www.google.com/search?q=raspberry+pi+set+environment+variable Did you try anything like that yet?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set the environment variable at the operating system level, but you can do it in your code like this:

```
from google.cloud import firestore
import google.cloud.exceptions

def quickstart_new_instance():
    # [START quickstart_new_instance]
    from google.cloud import firestore

    # Set GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variable
    os.environ["GCLOUD_PROJECT"] = "1234"

    # Project ID is determined by the GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variable
    db = firestore.Client()
    # [END quickstart_new_instance]

    return db
```